# Closed - Firebase Admin SDK, Firebase Framework SDK and Firebase Queue SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-queue

After a couple of day I found that:

Javascript Firebase SDK should be used on **client** side.
Javascript Firebase Admin SDK should be used on **server** side with Node.js.
Javascript Firebase Queue SDK should be used on **server** side to distribute background work on server with a faster response.

**References about Firebase Queue:**

- [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snVGSp0LW-I) explains admirably the usage of Firebase Queue.
- In the [Firebase Queue Github project](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue), the [guide](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue/blob/master/docs/guide.md) was not updated and then just today I found [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue/issues/90).

**Notes:**

- Why isn't there any documentation about Firebase Queue in the Firebase Documentation page? Neither a mention.
- Javascript Firebase Admin SDK is the new Javascript Firebase Server SDK package. It was changed a few days ago.
- There was some synchronisation problems on documentation with migration from Firebase Service functionality to Firebase Admin.

Thanks for support.

Comment: I have edited the topic. Is it ok now?